# How to cleanly cut cake into even slices

Tags: food

Whenever I have a cake or some other bread item, I can never get a good cut  while keeping the pieces even. Usually I use a knife, but that takes more work than I would like and I usually can't get a clean, straight cut.

Is there any good item or method to get a clean cut without too much work? I would prefer not to have to buy anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A very good method for cutting anything from cake to bread to cheese is to use dental floss. You can run the floss through the cake and it will allow you to get a precision cut. This is very quick and leaves clean cuts. It is also very easy to get even slices.

[image]
<sub>(source: [instructables.com](https://cdn.instructables.com/F17/6FN2/HWJJYW2A/F176FN2HWJJYW2A.LARGE.gif))</sub>

I do not own this. From [Instructables](https://www.instructables.com/How-to-Cut-a-Cake-With-Floss/)

You can also use other thin wires such as:

- Fishing line
- String
- Sewing thread

Comment: The sewing thread (I use stout button thread) is great for cutting cakes horizontally (a key part of creating a Schwarzwalder). For cutting a complicated layered cake into actual slices an electric carving knife is ideal.